# Excel 2003: automatic highlight of identical cell

Tags: excel, highlight

I want to automatically highlight any cell in a column (e.g. Column A) that is identical.  The cells contain characters (e.g. Arm Chair) and not values.  Any formula to do this?

Comment: Hi @SummerAntonio and welcome to stackoverflow, you might wonder why your post is downvoted? That is probably because you did not show us what you have tried. Many of us wants to help colleagues in trouble, but we do not want to do your job. So describe what you have tried and what errors/problems you got into!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to highlight all instances of repeats (for example - if Arm Chair exists twice in column A both will be highlighted) then try this:

Select column A > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > type in this formula

`=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1`

Then select required format > OK

This works for numbers or text

If you want to highlight all repeats (but not the first instance) the change to this formula

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1`